# Display two mongo collection one after other

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collection in mongodb.
One collection has an object with some properties and the other collection has same object as an array with 2 more properties. Now I want to display all records of both collection as a single pageable response in mongo by unwinding the array of second collection so that all object are same along with combined count. Please suggest

Comment: I suggest putting them in the same collection.

Comment: Use the `$unionWith` operator